# Popup menu is not inflating

Tags: java, android, menu, layout-inflater, android-inflate

How can I create a custom popup menu class with OnMenuItemClickListeners? I can't seem to find any SO answers that use a seperate class to do so. They all do it in their activities, but I want a seperate popup menu class.

I've tried creating it:

```
public class AddPhotoMenu extends PopupMenu {
    public AddPhotoMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
        super(context, anchor);
    }

    @Override
    public void inflate(int menuRes) {
        super.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_fragevent_addphotos);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
        new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto:
                        //Inflate a layout
                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Take photo");

                        break;
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos:
                        //Inflate a layout

                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Select photo");
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
```

But the menu doesn't inflate when I call it.

```
 AddPhotoMenu addPhotoMenu = new AddPhotoMenu(this, mAddPhotosButton1);
 addPhotoMenu.show();
```

Comment: You have to call `inflate()` yourself. It doesn't run automatically.

Comment: hello, @david s.  please try my answer.

Comment: Hello @david s. please try my answer it might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addPhotoMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_fragevent_addphotos);
addPhotoMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(addPhotoMenu); 
// Need to add this line otherwise it won't work.
addPhotoMenu.show();
```

Credits to:

[PopupMenu onMenuItemClick not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59281744/popupmenu-onmenuitemclick-not-being-called/59281841#59281841)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a button and on click of that button the popup menu will show. Follow this to inflate a custom popup menu.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);   
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_fragevent_addphotos, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto:
                        //Inflate a layout
                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Take photo");

                        return true;
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos:
                        //Inflate a layout

                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Select photo");
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();//showing popup menu
        }
    });
```

Comment: How can I do it in a separate class? Right now my issue is after overriding the setOnMenuItemClickListener, the logs inside the switch statement are not working

Comment: have you tried my answer? And one thing you didn't return true inside setOnMenuItemClickListener. Please try once my answer, hope it will work.

Comment: it works, but my question is how can I make it in a separate class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AddPhotoMenu extends PopupMenu {
    public AddPhotoMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
        super(context, anchor);
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_fragevent_addphotos, getMenu());

    }

  

    @Override
    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
        new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto:
                        //Inflate a layout
                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Take photo");

                        break;
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos:
                        //Inflate a layout

                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Select photo");
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
```

try to inflate the menu layout from the constructor and you don't need to override the inflate method.

You can override setOnMenuItemClickListener from the Activity/Fragment and remove it from a custom class

```
 addPhotoMenu .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
           @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto:
                        //Inflate a layout
                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Take photo");

                        break;
                    case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos:
                        //Inflate a layout

                        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Select photo");
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: SerOnMenuItemClickListener isn't being called

Comment: I ended up doing this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281841/11110509

Comment: @davids. My solutions also work for you. Take a look at this also