# PopupMenu onMenuItemClick not being called

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a class AddPhotoMenu

```
public class AddPhotoMenu extends PopupMenu implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    public AddPhotoMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
        super(context, anchor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Called");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto:
                //Inflate a layout
                Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Take photo");

                break;
            case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos:
                //Inflate a layout

                Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Select photo");
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I create a new instance of it however the method onMenuItemClick is never called when I click on the menu items.

```
AddPhotoMenu addPhotoMenu = new AddPhotoMenu(this, mAddPhotosButton1);
addPhotoMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_fragevent_addphotos);
addPhotoMenu.show();
```

What is causing the issue?

**Edit:__________________________________________________**

XML of menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto"
        android:title="Take a photo"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos"
        android:title="Select photos"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You get an error? What error?

Comment: My bad not an error. An issue*. I can't figure out why onMenuItemClick isn't being called

Comment: Can you also post your menu code? The XML one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Called");
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_takephoto:
             //Inflate a layout
             Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Take photo");

             return true; // return true instead of break
         case R.id.popup_menu_fragevent_selectphotos:
             //Inflate a layout

             Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemClick: Select photo");
             return true; // return true instead of break

        }
return false;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You have to set `MenuItemClickListener` to your popup menu like below.

```
AddPhotoMenu addPhotoMenu = new AddPhotoMenu(this, mAddPhotosButton1);
addPhotoMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_fragevent_addphotos);

addPhotoMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(addPhotoMenu); // add this line

addPhotoMenu.show();
```

Comment: it's still not being called

Answer (score 0):

You PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener should be implemented in the Activity or Fragment where you instantiate your PopupMen.
After that `addPhotoMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)` should be called, where "this" represents your Fragment or Activity.